# How to make a cyclorotor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I have looked for a way to make a cyclorotor mechanism which allows the blades to rock/rotate (in the picture below, its rocking I believe) to no avail. I am not able to find the required length of the green link or that green circle (refer picture). Any idea on how to find out the required length? also, how to determine the eccentricity?

The picture drawn using paint was the idea I was working on. Here the blade is supposed to spin by 180 degrees when the whole system completes one rotation with intermediate positions as shown in the figure. I am not able to determine the length of the remaining links to connect the system. I was thinking on the lines of 4 (or is it 5?) bar mechanisms as in two of the links have been given in each quadrant but cant find any logical way to find the remaining links.

please help ! [image: my idea]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you're really trying to do. In the meantime, your upper diagram isn't quite consistent. If we take the arm at 3 o'clock we have 90° between the blade and link. At 6 o'clock it's 135°, at 9 o'clock it's 180° (so it increased by 45° twice). Then the link/blade direction reverses and by 12 o'clock it has moved by 135° anti-clockwise followed by a 45° clockwise rotation when it gets back to 3 o'clock. To be more consistent the 12 o'clock blade should have a slope of -1, not the slope of 1 shown. Darn! I've just realised that this question is 2.5 years old!

Comment: Are you trying to build a Voith Schneider propeller?

Comment: sounds like a swashplate but for blades in a different direction...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use a link and have it follow a path something like a ring cam to control the blade pitch however you like.

Comment: Welcome on the Engineering SE! I suggest to write more, what is obvious for you, might be not for the readers of the future.